# how to intercept the network requests inside a website using a proxy package like http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

How can I intercept the network requests inside a site that is running as a `proxy-site` using `http-proxy-middleware`?

```js
app.use('/',, (req, res, next) => { 
  const { createProxyMiddleware,responseInterceptor } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

  const url = 'example.com';

  const homepage = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'example.com',
    changeOrigin: true, // for vhosted sites, changes host header to match to target's host
    logger: console,
    ws: true,
    selfHandleResponse:true,
    // hostRewrite: baseUrlBrowser, // Replace with your localhost and port
    secure: true,
    followRedirects: false,
      // });
       const modifiedHtml = $.html();
        res.send(modifiedHtml); 
       } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
       }
      
      //  res.send( buffer.toString('utf-8'));
      }),
 
  });

  homepage(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Proxy Error:', err.message);
      res.status(400).send('Proxy Error');
    }
  });
});
```